# laravel how to paginate single category posts

Tags: php, laravel

How can I paginate posts in single category page?

## Code

```
public function show($slug) {
   $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->where('online', true)->with(['posts' => function ($q) {
            $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');
            //I need this query be paginate
   }])->first();
   //return....
}
```

`my blade loop`

```
<h1>{{$category->name}}</h1>

@foreach($category->posts as $post)
  //post data here
@endforeach
```

Comment: Note to others: It seems like he wants to paginate the inner "posts" data, not the full query.

Comment: @Joseph exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship of categories and posts is n:n;

Because you just need one category, you just need to get posts by one category.

Try to use  another method:

```php
public function show($slug) {

   $cat = Category::where('slug', $slug)
                     ->where('online', true)
                     ->first();

   $posts = Post::join('category_posts', 'category_posts.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
                ->where('category_posts.category_id', $cat->id)
                ->selectRaw('posts.*')
                ->paginate(10);
   //return....
}
```

And in your blade loop:

```php
<h1>{{$cat->name}}</h1>

@foreach($posts as $post)
  //post data here
@endforeach
```

Comment: hi, my post table have not `category_id` column they are related by third table `category_posts`

Comment: I'm curious about the performance of 2 calls here vs 1 call by chaining.

Comment: @Joseph Two querys need to take them out from database twice, it cost times by IO.  But the first call is easy and small. so we can ignore it here.  And if you want to merge it to one query. can use ```where select```

Answer (score 0):

here is the exact example which I always use in my several project.

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request){
   $parts = BikeParts::paginate(5); //you can change how many you want


   return view('admin.bike_parts.index_excel', compact(['bike_parts']))->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5); // put exact number you are paginating , in here I used 5.
}
```

View:

```
  <table class="table table-actions-bar m-b-0">
  <tbody>
 <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>id</th>
         <th>PartNo.</th>
         <th>Part Name</th>
         <th>model</th>
         <th>Retail Price</th>
         </tr>
</thead>
 @foreach($bike_parts as $bike_part)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#,{{$bike_part->id}}">{{$loop->index+1}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$bike_part->part_number}}</td>
        <td>{{$bike_part->description}}</td>
        <td>{{$bike_part->bike_model}}</td>
        <td>{{$bike_part->retail_price}}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
{!! $bike_parts->render() !!}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for sharing. I'm not saying is a bad way but i'm sure there is cleaner way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `first()`, use `paginate(count)`

Here is an example according to your code,

```
public function show($slug) { 
    $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)
        ->where('online', true)
        ->with(['posts' => function ($q) { 
            $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');  
        }])->paginate(10); 
    //return.... 
}
```

Comment: that would return error i assume as my query is to find 1 category based on `slug` is not multiple category to use `paginate()` instead of `first()` *Again i assume*

Answer (score 0):

$posts = Post::where('category_id', $categoryId)->paginate(10);

Comment: hi, my post table have not `category_id` column they are related by third table `category_posts`

Answer (score 0):

Heres a way that may be used to achieve paginated posts in **multiple** category

However, I suspect that this will make a N+1 query. Might need eager loading implemented with this. Can someone confirm this ?

```
// Category.php (Model)
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\posts', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

In the blade file

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <h1>{{$category->name}}</h1>

    @foreach($category->posts()->paginate() as $post)
        //post data here
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```